# Solve a Linear Equation $y=\frac{x+3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $$y=\frac{x+3}{2}$$

The questions are

(a)What is the value of $\frac{x+3}{2}$ when $x=1$?

(b) What is the value of $x$ when $\frac{x+3}{2}=2$?

Please note that I am not familiar with these types of questions so can anyone tell me where to start and how to do this?

Comment: It has infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For the first part, just substitute $x=1$ in $\frac{x+3}{2}$. What do you get? $$y = \frac{x+3}{2}\bigg \lvert_{x =1} = \frac{\color{green}{1+ }\,3}{2}=2$$
- Can you do the same for the second part as well?

Comment: @TheMasterChief333 Do you want some more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is simply asking you to evaluate$y=\frac{x+3}{2}$ when $x=1$. By substituting in, we find $y=2$.

For part (b), it's asking us to find $x$ such that $\frac{x+3}{2}=2$. Multiplying both sides by $2$, we obtain $x+3=4$, so $x=1$.

Comment: Why to solve both parts if giving one solution and asking the OP to complete the other one can do more for him to understand...?

Answer (score 1):

For part a), you are solving for $y$ when $x=1$, so $y = \frac{1+3}{2}$ so $y=2$, you can check your answer by plugging in $y=2$,  so $2 = \frac{x+3}{2}$ and indeed $x=1$

For part b) it's giving you the $y$ value ($y=2$)  and you have to solve for $x$.  So just solving the equation will give you $x = 2(2)- 3 = 1$